# Office 365 VBA editor Find window (CTRL+F) always jumps to the dividing line between dual monitors

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word, office365, vbe

I recently started a new job and was given a brand-new system with dual displays and the current version of Microsoft Office 365. I've discovered a display issue in the Office VBA editor which affects Word, Excel, and Access.

If the VBA editor is on the right-hand display, and the `Find` window is opened (CTRL+F), it snaps to the dividing line between the two monitors. The location of the main app window doesn't matter; the snapping occurs regardless of the main app window location. And the snapping cannot be disabled. See screenshots below.

Is there any way to resolve this..?

Furthermore, if the `Find` window is re-positioned, it snaps back again the next time the `Find Next` button is pressed. Simply put, any time the VBA editor window is on the second display, the `Find` window won't stay where the user positions it. It's always automatically re-positioned...and badly.

The hardware is a new Dell Latitude 7290, with WD19 port replicator and dual P2419H LCD displays.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not sure there's a solution for that. The VBE notoriously does whatever the heck it wants with its dialogs and toolwindows...

Comment: On the bright side, looks like the two monitors are nicely lined up! =)

Comment: Even better since I took the photo. They're now perfectly aligned and the gap masked by black electrical tape. =-D